# Talend tFileInputDelimited to tDBoutput ORA-00904

Tags: oracle, talend

I made a job design which consists of tFileInputDelimited -> tMap -> tDBOutput(Oracle)

The csv I am using has columns which are not currently in the table which I don't think should be a problem.. but when I run my job I get multiple ORA-00904 invalid identifier errors.

I check my DB in Oracle SQL developer and no rows have been updated.

Looking for some help how to fix this.. I looked up the error and I get referenced to a SQL code but I am not using SQL only a CSV file to upload.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that your csv has columns that are not in your table. That is a problem if you map those columns to the tMap output. Only those columns which are present in your target table need to be in the tMap output flow going to tDBOutput.

Comment: Would I need to create these variables in the table in order to export these column’s data?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. Do you want to insert those columns in the target table? If so, then you have to add them to the table beforehand (with an ALTER table statement for instance)

Comment: Thank you! Once I created the columns in the table I was able to extract all my CSV data to the Table.

Comment: Is there any way possible to have Talend create these column names when importing a CSV in the future rather than to create the variable in the TB through oracle?

Comment: Talend can't create the columns for you, but it can drop and recreate the whole table. You can select "drop and create table" from option "action on table" on the DB component, but this way the data is lost. It's not recommended to do this in a production environment :)